# How to calculate sparse values of matrix product memory-efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I would like to calculate some certain values of a matrix product, in a way that is efficient in memory usage and computation time. The problem is that the intermediate matrix has two very large dimensions and may not be storable.

Dimensions with example values:

```
N = 7  # very large
K = 3
M = 10 # very large
L = 8  # very very large
```

'a' is a matrix of shape (N,K) 
'b' is a matrix of shape (K,N)

```
a = np.arange(N*K).reshape(N,K)
b = np.arange(K*M).reshape(K,M)
```

rows is a array of indices with values within range(N) and length L 
cols is a array of indices with values within range(M) and length L

```
rows = [0,0,1,2,3,3,4,6]
cols = [0,9,5,8,2,8,3,6]
```

I need the following, but it is not possible to calculate a matrix `(a @ b)` with shape (MxN) as intermediate result because of its size:

```
values = (a @ b)[rows, cols]
```

An alternative implementation might involve
slicing a[rows] and b[:,cols], creating matrices with shape (L,K) and (K,L),
but those are too big also.
Numpy copies the values when doing fancy slicing

```
values = np.einsum("ij,ji->i", a[rows], b[:,cols])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide actual numbers (ballpark) for `K, N, M, L`?

Comment: How big is [rows, cols] aprrox. relative to the whole output? Only a few values, 5%,50% ?

Comment: at the moment I have `K=1e2, N=1e4, M=1e4, L=1e6` but i wanted my algorithm to be able to handle factor ten `K=1e3, N=1e5, M=1e5, L=1e7`

Comment: It is not possible to calculate `(a @ b)`, but is it possible to calculate `np.dot(a[np.unique(rows),:], b[:,np.unique(cols)])` ? Of course, it strongly depends on the nature of your `rows` and `cols` vectors.

Comment: I already removed every row and col without values so unique doesn't help in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to directly calculate the results. Maybe there are some other tricks to use a BLAS routine without a huge temporary array, but this will also work.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time


@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def sparse_mult(a,b_Trans,inds):
  res=np.empty(inds.shape[0],dtype=a.dtype)

  for x in nb.prange(inds.shape[0]):
    i=inds[x,0]
    j=inds[x,1]
    sum=0.
    for k in range(a.shape[1]):
      sum+=a[i,k]*b_Trans[j,k]
    res[x]=sum
  return res


#-------------------------------------------------
K=int(1e3)
N=int(1e5)
M=int(1e5)
L=int(1e7)

a = np.arange(N*K).reshape(N,K).astype(np.float64)
b = np.arange(K*M).reshape(K,M).astype(np.float64)

inds=np.empty((L,2),dtype=np.uint64)
inds[:,0] = np.random.randint(low=0,high=N,size=L) #rows
inds[:,1] = np.random.randint(low=0,high=M,size=L) #cols

#prepare
#-----------------------------------------------
#sort inds for better cache usage
inds=inds[np.argsort(inds[:,1]),:]

# transpose b for easy SIMD-usage
# we wan't a real transpose here not a view
b_T=np.copy(np.transpose(b))

#calculate results
values=sparse_mult(a,b_T,inds)
```

The calculation step, including the preperation (sorting, transpose of b matrix) should run in less than 60s.

Comment: Was going to try numba next. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to simply chunk your `einsum` approach. chopping up `rows` and `cols` into bits of size 20 solves the large (10^7) problem in ~2 min on my laptop. One can probably improve that by tweaking the chunk size.

But we can do better: We can group by either rows or cols (I chose cols) and then multiply individual cols with all paired rows. We can use sparse csc/csr matrices to do all the sorting/shuffling/reindexing for us. This method on the same data finishes in ~30 sec.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def f_sparse_helper(a, b, rows, cols):
    h = sparse.csr_matrix((np.empty(L), cols, np.arange(L+1)), (L, M)) \
              .tocsc()
    for i in range(M):
        l, r = h.indptr[i:i+2]
        h.data[l:r] = a[rows[h.indices[l:r]]] @ b[:, i]
    return h.tocsr().data

def f_chunk(a, b, rows, cols, chunk=20):
    out = np.empty(L)
    for j in range(0, rows.size, chunk):
        l = j+chunk
        out[j:l] = np.einsum("ij,ji->i", a[rows[j:l]], b[:,cols[j:l]])
    return out

def prep_data(K, M, N, L):
    a = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (N, K))
    b = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (K, M))
    rows = np.random.randint(0, N, (L,))
    cols = np.random.randint(0, M, (L,))
    return a, b, rows, cols

# use small exmpl to check correct
K, M, N, L = 10, 100, 100, 1000
a, b, rows, cols = prep_data(K, M, N, L)
res = f_sparse_helper(a, b, rows, cols)
assert np.allclose(res, np.einsum("ij,ji->i", a[rows], b[:,cols]))
assert np.allclose(res, f_chunk(a, b, rows, cols))

# timeit on big one
from time import perf_counter as pc
K, M, N, L = 1_000, 10_000, 10_000, 10_000_000
a, b, rows, cols = prep_data(K, M, N, L)
t = pc()
res_ch = f_chunk(a, b, rows, cols)
s = pc()
print('chunked      ', s-t, 'seconds')
t = pc()
res_sh = f_sparse_helper(a, b, rows, cols)
s = pc()
print('sparse helper', s-t, 'seconds')
assert np.allclose(res_sh, res_ch)
```

Sample run:

```
chunked       121.16188396583311 seconds
sparse helper 31.172512074932456 seconds
```